# Macro __HAL_TIM_SET_Compare does not work

Tags: c, gnu, stm32, stm32cubemx

Trying to adjust the PWM period value using the macro

```
__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim4,TIM_CHANNEL_3,299);
```

but it does not work.

However the macro

```
__HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim4, 599);
```

works fine.

why the `__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE` does not work ?.

The board I am using is NUCLEO-F401RE with CUBE-MX generated project on Truestudio.

Comment: And if you enable preload register first? Saying *not working* is very strong. Is the value written to register?

Comment: @tilz0r the __HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE confirms the register value is loaded :- Current ARR=599 CRR=299

Comment: Then macro works ok. You will need to focus to somewhere else instead.

Comment: @tilz0r .. seeking help .. any lead where to look for ?, If I use HAL_TIM_ConfigChannel(...) it works fine..  but I think doing it via Macro is more elegant

Comment: Check what is different in config channel versus what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with this macro, and would opt instead for:

```
htim4.Instance->CCR3=299;
```

Supposing you want to set the capture and compare register of channel three for `htim4` to 299 to modify your PWM duty cycle.